# Rotating a css sprite when changing direction of motion in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to rotate a prototype css sprite everytime its direction of motion changes. So imagine a car that rotates everytime it changes direction so that its hood is always facing in the direction of its motion.

In the **html**, I got a div element named car.

In the **css** I've simply defined it as a green rectangle (so you know which way the hood/front is facing).

```js
var car = document.getElementById('car');
car.style.top = '0px';
car.style.left = '0px';

var angle = 0;

document.addEventListener('keydown', function(keyPressed) {
  if (keyPressed.keyCode == 37) {
    car.style.left = (parseInt(car.style.left) - 5) + 'px';
    if (angle >= 90 && angle <= 260) {
      angle = angle + 10;
      car.style.transform = 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)';
    } else if (angle <= 80 && angle >= -80) {
      angle = angle - 10;
      car.style.transform = 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)';
    }
  } else if (keyPressed.keyCode == 39) {
    car.style.left = (parseInt(car.style.left) + 5) + 'px';
    if (angle >= -90 && angle <= 80) {
      angle = angle + 10;
      car.style.transform = 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)';
    } else if (angle <= 260 && angle >= 100) {
      angle = angle - 10;
      car.style.transform = 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)';
    }
  }
});
```

```css
#car {
  height: 30px;
  width: 20px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #00ff00;
}
```

```html
<html lang='en'>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='.css'>
  <div id='car'></div>
</head>

<body>
  <script src='.js'></script>
</body>

</html>
```

In my javascript I've coded the sprite to move along the x-axis when you press the left and right arrow keys. The sprite is also meant to rotate clockwise during a change in direction of motion. The problem is that once you rotate the sprite 270 degrees, it no longer rotates anymore.

Give it a fiddle and you'll see what I mean. Steer the sprite towards the right until it rotates 90 degrees and then change the direction to the left, once the sprite rotates 270 degrees, it no longer rotates upon change in direction.

As I understand, this is because 270 degrees is a blindspot in the code. How can I fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: please create the fiddle yourself and attach it to this question.

Comment: @krecik2000 is this question still open ?

Answer (score 0):

When pressing right always increase the angle, and when pressing left always decrease the angle. Then just noermalize the rotation when getting to 360 or negative deg.

```
if (keyPressed.keyCode == 37) {
      car.style.left = (parseInt(car.style.left) - 5) + 'px';
      angle += 10;
      car.style.transform = 'rotate('+ angle +'deg)';
      }
} else if (keyPressed.keyCode == 39) {
      car.style.left = (parseInt(car.style.left) - 5) + 'px';
      angle -= 10;
      car.style.transform = 'rotate('+ angle +'deg)';
}
if(angle < 0){
      angle+=360;
}
if(angle > 360)
      angle -= 360;
}
```